# How to create 2 or two sequential network requests with RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have created two different API requests with Retrofit 2.0  as

```
Observable<T> getOrganisationList()
Observable<T> getStaffList()
```

I am using `CompositeDisposable` container that can hold onto multiple other disposables. I want the above two observable requests to be executed sequentially (`getStaffList()` after `getOrganisationList()`) only and only if:

1. `getOrganisationList()` doesn't throws request time out
2. `getOrganisationList()` doesn't throws network exception in case of no network available
3. `getOrganisationList()` doesn't indicates session timeout by sending a result code in json object
4. `getOrganisationList()` doesn't throws `JSONException` while parsing the result
5. `getOrganisationList()` doesn't returns null or empty result

**Please answer the question with the help of the code.**

Comment: You should be fine just with `Observable.concat()`. All of the cases you've described throws exception except empty result. This means, `onError` is called in subscriber and second observable `getStaffList()` in concat is not realized. You can handle empty result for example in `flatmap()` operator and throw exception in that case too.

Comment: What @skywall said, with the addition of `.switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(...))`

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I'm not sure you are right. `switchIfEmpty()` is invoked, when no item is emitted. In this case, empty list is going to be emitted.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Thank-you for the inputs. It would be good if you could answer the question with the code.

Comment: @skywall  Thank-you for the inputs. It would be good if you could answer the question with the code.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in case you use RxJava2 and Retrofit2, replace your `Observable`'s with `Single`'s. Result of `Single` is exactly one `onSuccess()` or exactly one `onError()` method call. `Observable` is more generic.

```
public void func() {
    Disposable disposable = Single.concat(getOrganisationList(), getStaffList())
            .subscribe(result -> {
                // called twice, when organisation call succeeded and when staff call succeeded
            }, throwable -> {
                // handle exceptions you want
                if (throwable instanceof NullPointerException) {
                    // organisation - empty or null; staff - null
                } // else if(throwable instanceof IOException) ...
            });
}

public Single<List<String>> getOrganisationList() {
    return Single.just(Collections.singletonList("Hello")) // (1)
            .map(organizations -> {
                if (organizations.isEmpty()) {
                    throw Exceptions.propagate(new NullPointerException("List is empty"));
                }
                return organizations;
            }).doOnSuccess(organizations -> {
                // do something with organizations list
            });
}

public Single<List<Integer>> getStaffList() {
    return Single.just(Collections.<Integer>emptyList()) // (2)
            .doOnSuccess(organizations -> {
                // do something with staff list
            });
}
```

You should add your API calls to places marked as (1) and (2). Instead of your generic type `T` I have used `String` and `Integer` to make sure code can be compiled.

Comment: Thank-you for the very specific explanation. Let me implement it. I will revert in sometime. In the meanwhile if you could suggest an answer for the stackoverflow.com/q/44322223/2870088 which is opposite of this question. It would be of great help.

Comment: I am up voting this as this answer helped me to some extent in guiding.